# preg_replace is only replacing part of the input? ( Regex Help )

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

I have this function which is used for BBcodes on my site. I am using preg_replace.

```
function makebbcode($bbpost) {
    $bbfind = array(
        '~\@(.*?)~s'
    );
    $bbreplace = array(
        '<a href="http://www.google.com">@$1</a>'
    );
    $bbpost = preg_replace($bbfind, $bbreplace, $bbpost);
    //Once BBcodes and icons are put in, return.
    return $bbpost;
}
```

The point of this is to make it so you can put @username and it becomes a link to their profile. ( www.google.com is a test example. ) But the code is just making the @ symbol a link, rather than the whole @username.

That being said, it looks like it's completely ignoring (.*?) for some reason. I'm sure my regex is off, but I can't figure out exactly what IS off, and I couldn't find anything online that could help... or at least something I could understand. ( Beginner at regex )

Comment: Ungreedy `(.*?)` doesn't make much sense if it isn't followed by something else.

Comment: And what is the example of the input text?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The lazy quantifier `?` is matching the words as few times as possible.
In this case, that means **0 times**.

Try removing the `?`
or adding something after it which forces it to match the word,

Example: `\@(.*?)$`

Comment: Why to use `?` if you're proposing to use `$` anchor? In case of `$` in the end - `.*?` will **always** match the whole string, regardless of if it is greedy or not.

Comment: Without an anchor of some kind, it will match nothing.

Comment: That's right. But with `$` anchor `?` becomes useless. `@(.*?)$` regex is identical to `@(.*)$`

Comment: The expression is valid. Whether or not you think it's useless is your opinion. There's no such rules in regex.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot, and I looked into the $ anchor. Not sure why this got down voted though.

Comment: @mega: it is downvoted because in `@(.*?)$` regular expression `?` quantifier makes no sense, and instead of fixing it they decided to argue with no good reason.